# How can I catch outbound link click on an Angular 1.x website?

Tags: angularjs, google-analytics, seo

I'm trying to catch link clicks to external websites, to track them later.

Something like `<a href="#" ng-click="click()">foo</a>` but across all DOM tree.

Most of a content is coming from external REST server, thus I cannot use `ng-click` there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can do is write a directve named `a`

```
angular.module('tracking', [])
.directive('a', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E'
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.on('click', function() {
        if (attrs.target == outside-target)
        //your logic
      })
    }
  }
}`
```

important logical part would be

```
     if (attrs.target == outside-target)
        //your logic
      })
```

Comment: Noway! I didn't know you can override existing tags. It's awesome, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this works only with links I'm building myself with Angular. It doesn't catch any links from dynamic content.

Comment: you might not be compiling the dynamic html added with angular scope... you will need to do that.. how are you adding dynamic html content? thru some directive?

Comment: I'm doing it with `ng-bind-html="$sce.htmlSafe(text)"`.

Comment: Right, if I render html via `$compile` it works just fine. Thanks a lot!